# Promise.all() for a promiseArray not returning any values

Tags: javascript, promise, axios

I have the following setup where I am trying to make a call to a function which returns a `Promise`, which in turn has a `Promise.all()` call to make an indefinite number of `axios.post()` calls. I tried using `axios.all()` and `axios.spread(...responses)`, but no luck. I've also tried a number of examples posted to SO from experienced users. But still no luck.

It's worth noting that the calls *are* being made, it's just that the responses being returned are undefined.

The function being called is the following:

```
createSurveyResult(surveyResults) {
  let token = Vue.prototype.$auth.getLocalStorage(`${this.activeUser.uuid)_{process.env.NODE_ENV}_ACCESS_TOKEN`)

  if (token) {
    axiosModified.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`
  }

  return new Promise(resolve => {
    let promiseArray = surveyResults.map(payload => {
      axiosModified.post('/feedback/results/', payload)
    })

    Promise.all(promiseArray).then(responses => {
      responses.forEach(res => console.log(res))
      console.log('submitted all axios calls');
      resolve(responses)
    }).catch(error => {
      resolve(error.response)
    })
  })
}
```

Which is being called as:

```
this.$surveys.createSurveyResult(surveyResults).then((responses) => {
  console.log(responses)
});
```

Yet, both the `console.log(res)` res objects return are undefined within the `Promise.all()` , the `console.log('submitted all` axios `calls');` is being called, and the responses from the then() callback are returned as:

[image: Promise.all()]

I'm wondering what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: because the callback in the `surveyResults.map()` method doesn't return anything

Comment: @GuyIncognito Perfect, thank you - it was literally a case of removing the `{}` inside the return map call. D'oh!

Comment: or adding `return` before `axiosModified.post`

Comment: FYI, wrapping the `Promise.all()` in a `new Promise()` is an anti-pattern. You don't need to create another promise if you already have one (i.e. the one that `Promise.all()` creates). Simply return the `Promise.all()` instead and use `return responses` instead of `resolve(responses)`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it

Comment: Ahh yes, quite right. Think I'm just bastardising code over code and not really thinking here. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Write your function like this:

```
createSurveyResult(surveyResults) {
  let token = Vue.prototype.$auth.getLocalStorage(
    `${this.activeUser.uuid}_${process.env.NODE_ENV}_${ACCESS_TOKEN}`
  );

  if (token) {
    axiosModified.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;
  }

  return Promise.all(
    surveyResults.map((payload) =>
      axiosModified.post("/feedback/results/", payload)
    )
  );
}
```